# How do I add modelstate error to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

I have a view that uses a list of modelitems like this:

```
List<It4You.AlertBrick.Library.Domain.Order.AbOrderLineItemPicked>
```

When I get this list serverside I check if this is one type of item, it has to have a valid serial number. If its another type I check if the user has put a checkmark in the "picked" checkbox. If both of these fails, I would like to add a modelstate error to this row. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can quite simply add directly into `ModelState` as key/value pairs:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("error", "Serial is invalid");
```

and then in your view: `@Html.ValidationMessage("error")`.

Comment: How would you specifically add error to show up side by side with the error property? Say for example I have an editor template for the list item type and on that I have specified ValidationMessageFor that property...

Comment: Just set the key to be the property name, e.g. `ModelState.AddModelError("User.Password", "Invalid password");`

Comment: Thanks! How to go about if the first property is a collection and I need to show the error next to a specific property of an arbitrary item. Will [] work here?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `for` loop to set error in list.
e.g.;

```
 for (int i = 0; i <mylist.Count(); i++)
 {
  if (dmylist[i].prop1== null)
     ModelState.AddModelError("dmylist[" + i + "].prop1", "prop1 is required.");
 }
```